# Avoid e-notation using net.sf.json-lib

Tags: java, json, xml, json-lib

I'm using com.hynnet.json-lib to convert XML to JSON.
PB here is that for long integers this library use exponents instead of full-number.

Could I avoid it using this library or should I use another one?

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<rootTag>
    <_id type="number">7000000001</_id>
</rootTag>
```

My convertion-code:

```
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
xmlSerializer.clearNamespaces();
xmlSerializer.setSkipNamespaces(true);
xmlSerializer.setForceTopLevelObject(false);
net.sf.json.JSON json = xmlSerializer.read(xmlString);
```

Result json:

> {"_id": 7.000000001E9}

Expected json:

> {"_id": 7000000001}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Found the reason of such behavior. Double.valueof(String) returns exponential view. Bug on library's side.